# How can I push my ReactJS gh-pages without error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, github-pages

Can someone please tell me why my react page is not deploying on github pages. Whenever I try opening it, it shows a 404 error page, however the app works perfectly fine on my local machine without any error or warning. I updated my package.json and also installed gh-pages as a dev dependency. This is
[my repo](https://github.com/var-greyShader/pokedex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The homepage in the package.json isn't set to https://pokedex-tan.vercel.app/

Try changing `"homepage": "http://canaryGrapher.github.io/pokedex",` to `"homepage": "https://pokedex-tan.vercel.app/",`